# Sharing data with child components without props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sharing data with child components like the code below.

```
const App = () => {
  const [appData, setAppData] = useState({});

  const dealId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('dealId');

  useEffect(() => {
    /* API Call here */,
        (response) => {
          setAppData(
            Object.entries(response).reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
              return {
                ...previousValue,
                [currentValue[0]]: currentValue[1].data(),
              };
            }, {})
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }, [dealId]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CSSBaseline />
      <NavAppBar dealId={dealId} user={appData.user} />
      <Panel>
        <Contact
          contact={appData.contact}
          contactFields={appData.contactFields}
        />
        <Event event={appData.event} />
        <Accommodation
          packageItemFields={appData.packageItemFields}
          packageItems={appData.packageItems}
          hotels={appData.hotels}
        />
        <Course courses={appData.courses} event={appData.event} />
        <Transportation transportationFields={appData.transportationFields} />
      </Panel>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This feels like not a good pattern since I need to pass the same data more than one time to different components. Is there any way to improve on this? Using context would be more suitable?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head–I'd explore putting commonly reused data into either context or something like Redux.

Comment: CreateContext in parent, UseContext in children

Comment: @LMulvey I've read about Redux, I tried grasping it, but couldn't. What's the purpose of Redux?

Comment: @EugenSunic Nice, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb that will help you in deciding when is the right time to add state management like Context api or Redux that I use is when I see myself prop drilling heavy now I then turn to using Context Api.

Ask yourself the following questions below before even deciding between Context or Redux

**When should I use Context Api?**

**Ans:** If you are using Redux only to avoid passing props down to deeply nested components, then you could replace Redux with the Context API

**So when should I use Redux?**

**Ans:** Redux is a state container, handling your application's logic outside of your components, putting your entire app state in one container, using Redux DevTools to track when, where, why, and how your application's state changed, or using plugins such as Redux Saga,Redux Persist, etc.

In This case you can use Redux.

**So now if you keep this ideas in mind then you will choose wisely**

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure. Good luck on your project **Happy Coding!**